# How to refactor rust code so that borrow-checking errors are performed at runtime instead of compile time?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have the following minimal reproducible example, somewhat contrived, rust code which consists of 3 structs: `State`, `Engine` and `Session`.

`Engine` is an object that creates short-lived "sessions" that keep a reference to the engine. These sessions also maintain a vector of strings. Strings can be added to the session with `add()`. When the session is dropped, it calls `end()` on the Engine and prints out all the strings it gathered.

Only one session can be created at a time; rust's borrow checker enforces this.

```rust
// Engine

struct Engine {}

impl Engine {
    fn begin<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Session<'a> {
        Session {
            parent: self,
            items: vec![],
        }
    }

    fn end(&mut self, items: &Vec<String>) {
        println!("Submitted items: {}", items.join(", "));
        // Modify some state on self here...
    }
}

// Session

struct Session<'a> {
    parent: &'a mut Engine,
    items: Vec<String>,
}

impl <'a> Session<'a> {
    fn add(&mut self, s: &str) {
        self.items.push(s.to_owned());
    }
}

impl <'a> Drop for Session<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.parent.end(&self.items);
    }
}

// State

struct State {
    engine: Engine,
}

fn main() {
    let mut state = State {
        engine: Engine {},
    };

    {
        let mut session = state.engine.begin();
        session.add("apple");
        session.add("banana");
    }

    {
        let mut session = state.engine.begin();
        session.add("coconut");
        session.add("durian");
    }
}
```

This outputs the following ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3a1a0b3b9f71fea81d7d4d30f646ff32)):

```
Submitted items: apple, banana
Submitted items: coconut, durian
```

I would like to refactor this so that I can store the current session inside `State` instead of needing to keep its lifetime tied to the scope it was created within. The session can then be accessed on the state by another function.

I made these modifications but it doesn't compile and I get a bunch of errors about borrowing mutably multiple times and `state` not living long enough:

```rust
struct State<'a> {
    engine: Engine,
    session: Option<Session<'a>>,
}

impl <'a> State<'a> {
    fn next_session(&'a mut self) {
        self.session = Some(self.engine.begin());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut state = State {
        engine: Engine {},
        session: None,
    };

    state.next_session();
    state.session.as_mut().unwrap().add("apple");
    state.session.as_mut().unwrap().add("banana");

    state.next_session();
    state.session.as_mut().unwrap().add("coconut");
    state.session.as_mut().unwrap().add("durian");
}
```

Essentially I want manual control over the creation and destruction of each session, but I don't think this is possible to achieve without doing dodgy unsafe things to circumvent rust's borrow checker. I can modify `State` but I cannot modify `Engine` or `Session` in any way. Is this possible to do somehow? With `Rc` and/or `RefCell` maybe, or `Box`? I understand it's too complex for rust to figure out at compile time, so can this be deferred to runtime?

Comment: Can you modify `Session` and `Engine`?

Comment: No, they are actually types in a crate I'm using. `State` is my code.